# R&R not authorized for cluster error

Tags: ibm-cloud, retrieve-and-rank

I'm getting a not authorized when accessing one of the clusters I created. I can't even delete it.

Error from server at https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/solr_clusters/sc7eb72dcd_f6c6_4608_a9d4_4a406c0bbc2d/solr:

> WRRCSH004: Service [9643ff04-1fb4-4c73-b73b-bdf7fea1975a] is not
>   authorized for cluster [sc7eb72dcd_f6c6_4608_a9d4_4a406c0bbc2d]!

I even tried deleting it from the UI:

[image]

How can I request to get it deleted for me?

Answer (score 0):

If you need someone to delete it for you, please open a ticket for Bluemix Support using this URL: http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport